# is this global variables? PHP

Tags: php

i dont know what is the name of this line of code.. and i don't even know if im doing the right structure of code.. i can't research to google because i don't know what to search.. :)

anyway, here's the code..

```
<?php
$hello = 1;

switch($hello)
{
  case 1:
    FOO:
    break;

  case 2:
    BAR:
    break;

}


FOO:
echo "hello world!";

BAR:
echo "hola world!";

?>
```

if the value of $hello == 1, does the output will be "hello world!"?
if the value of $hello == 2, does the output will be "hola world!"?

i got this to work..

```
<?php
$hello = '1';

switch($hello)
{
  case '1':
    goto FOOO;
    break;

  case '2':
    goto BARR;
    break;

}


FOOO:
echo "hello world!";
goto LAST;

BARR:
echo "hola world!";

LAST:
?>
```

thanks for the suggestions and answers.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `someText:` syntax is used for [`goto` control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php).

Actually, your code isn't doing what it is expected to do. I thought it would not run, but maybe it does.

In all cases, it will just output `hello world!hola world!`, since the `switch` does nothing, and two `echo`s are executed then.

Probably, what was expected is to have two `goto` inside the switch. In this case, if `$hello` is equal to 1, the code will display `hello world!hola world!`, and if it is equal to 2, only `hola world!` will be displayed. Note that you should avoid using `goto` when possible, so here, [the answer by Crayon Violent to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648553/is-this-global-variables-php/3648566#3648566) contains a better alternative (even if the flow is modified and will give other results than with gotos).

Comment: It doesn't run, but yes, if it did, you would be correct. If the code was functional, then I suppose `$hello == 2;` would come up with only `hola world!`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the switch won't execute anything, it's essentially `switch(1)`, which will match `case 1`, and that will be it. It's almost identical to the example given for switch statements. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: @Robert: sorry, my answer is not probably too explicit. And now it's even less, since the code will not run ("label FOO is already defined" error). But *if* it was a valid code, the switch will *execute*, but will *do* nothing: neither changing the app flow, nor outputting anything nor changing any variables.

Comment: Right, I must have misunderstood, I thought you were saying the switch would not execute.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$hello = 1;

switch($hello)
{
  case 1:
    FOO();
    break;

  case 2:
    BAR();
    break;

}


function FOO() {
  echo "hello world!";
}

function BAR() {
  echo "hola world!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Or keeping the goto's you can figure out the solution using the manual: http://php.net/goto

Comment: Note that you modified the application flow. Actually, putting gotos will result in `hello world!hola world!`, while in your solution, it will display `hello world!` only.

Comment: well it seems to me from the OP that he wanted to only display one, based on the value of $hello

Comment: I agree. That's also why `goto` must be avoided when possible: it's sometimes too ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a fatal error because it will tell you that `label FOO is already defined`.

Crayon Violet has a good workaround for this. I would recommend his method, as you will not have to work with GOTOs. Not that GOTOs are bad when used correctly, but in this situation, I would say it wouldn't be a good use of them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking what global scope is.

```
$hello = 1;

$hello = 'hello world!';
$hola = 'hola world!';

function globalvars($x) {
    global $hello,$hola;
    switch($x)
    {
      case 1:
        echo $hello;
        break;
      case 2:
        echo $hola;
        break;
    }
}

globalvars($hello); // "hello world!"
globalvars(2); // "hola world!"
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php